# grails jasper plugin report pdf display

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I am using the grails jasper plugin to generate reports in my grails application. It works fine but it offers the pdf report as a download, is there a way to display the report in the browser, lets say on another tab.

this is the code to display the report.

```
<g:jasperReport jasper="myreport" format="PDF" name="MY Report" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inline="true"`, like

```
< g:jasperReport jasper="myreport" inline="true" format="PDF" name="MY Report" />
```